# Search in hierarchical tree on neo4j

Tags: search, neo4j, tree, cypher

I have a database organized in several hierarchical trees. 
Nodes are organized by number.Nodes that begin with the same number are interconnected by relationships. For example: (5)-[connect]-(50)-[connect]-(507)... etc. I want to search, for example, the node 301 starting from the first parent node: the node 3. How do I do this query in cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for a specific node starting from the first parent I would suggest following query:

```
MATCH (n {number:1})-[:CONNECT*0..]->(n1) return n, n1;
```

This query searches for the node with property `number = 1` and searches for all children which are related through `CONNECT` relationship. If you want to search for a specific child node you have to change the query this way:

```
 MATCH (n {number:1})-[:CONNECT*0..]->(n1 {number:101}) return n, n1;
```

In the `*0..` part you can define until what depth you want to search, so you can also search for depth=n with `*0..n`. This documentation is a good place to start with the match/path clause: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/

Comment: Please take a look at https://neo4j.com/blog/graph-search-algorithm-basics/ You will find there some useful informations. You may also look at https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures which has an implementation of the Dijkstra’s Algorithm.